# Mistake in the proof that a domain is flat as a module over any subring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, tensor-products

Where is the mistake in the following argument? I feel that there has to be one, for example by the very existence of [this article](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/205/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01190228.pdf?auth66=1383224155_86ada5fdef59720f9d539256cc727f07&ext=.pdf).

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $S \subseteq R$ be a subring of $R$. Then $R$ is a flat $S$-module.

To show this, we consider the equivalent condition that for any ideal $I \unlhd S$ it holds that the mapping $I \otimes_S R\rightarrow S \otimes_S R \cong R, f \otimes r \mapsto fr$ is injective. But since $R$ is a domain, it has to even hold that $I \otimes_S R \cong (I) \unlhd R$ via the mapping mentioned above. That this mapping is well defined and surjective is pretty easy to see, the injectivity is the interesting part (for the flatness as well). Let $f \otimes r \in I \otimes_S R$ be in the kernel of this mapping. This means that $fr = 0$, in $R$. Since $R$ is a domain, it has to hold that $f$ or $r$ is already $0$ in $R$, but then it is also already $f \otimes r = 0 \in I \otimes_S R$, so the mapping is injective.

I feel I am missing something pretty big somewhere, but I honestly don't see the error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as I know the elements in $I\otimes_SR$ are sums of elements of the form $f\otimes r$.

Comment: In other words, you have shown that there can be no pure tensors in the kernel, which means very little!

Comment: Yes, that's it... Thanks, I knew it was something as basic as that, but since you can work with pure tensors a lot of times as they generate $I \otimes_S R$ you tend to forget that here you do need a general element here. So, I'm pretty new to stackexchange too, should I just anwser it myself, or can I make the comment the anwser?

Comment: @goens I'd like to invite you to answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem lies therin, that a general element of $I \otimes_S R$ is not a pure tensor, of the form $ f \otimes r$ in the notation above, but rather $S$-linear combinations of such tensors.

Thus, in the proof we only show that there are no pure tensors in the kernel of the mapping, and not that it is injective.